# Unable to access custom module from submodules in Angular

Tags: angular

I created one custom module (which would be published as npm module later - Now it is located locally outside of my project folder.)

Now I'm injecting this custom module in my project root module (i.e., app.module.ts). It is working fine.

But when I try to inject this custom module to other modules in the same project., I got the StaticInjectError & NullinjectorError. No provider for Logprovider

[Please click to view the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sB7GP.png)
[Appmodule screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYHnU.png)

Comment: you didn't mention your error

Comment: @Md.Rafee, can you tell me what I did wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Define the custom module in the import field inside the module.ts file of the module you want to use. Like below.

```
{
      imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, TheCustomModule ],
      declarations: [ AppComponent ],
      bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
}
```

Comment: I did. But it is only working in appmodule & appcomponent. It doesn't work apart from the root module. I added multiple modules in my project. I want to use this custom module service in all project modules. As of now, my root module has the access.

Comment: @Jeni try adding `TheCustomModule.forRoot()`

Comment: Try to add over the export line. Like this.

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TheCustomModule{

}

Comment: @Todamal, [Please check the following screenshot][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYHnU.png

Answer (score 0):

*Option 1:*
You can add your **Logprovider** as a provider inside your providers array in your custom module

Like this:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
   ...ModulesToImport
  ],
  declarations: [
   ...ComponentsToImport
  ],
  providers: [LogProvider]
})
```

Then you need to import that custom module to your **other_module.module.ts** file
Like this:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
   CustomModule
  ],
  declarations: [
   ...ComponentsToImport
  ],
  providers: [...ServicesToImport]
})
```

---

*Option 2:*
In your Other_Component.component.ts you can add your **LogProvider** directly, like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-other-component',
  templateUrl: './other-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./other-component.component.scss'],
  providers: [LogProvider]
})
```